# Can't find my db or my collection even though it's there

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image: mongodb sheel]

As you can from the image, both my db and my collection exist. Why Am I getting a Reference Error ?

Comment: Your In the shell `db` is your database instance

Comment: Also please copy and past the terminal output instead of the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell, `db` is your database instance thus `scene_db`. Simply use it like this:

```
db.scene_collection.insert({'key': 'value'})
```